# Node.js MongoError: First argument to $slice must be an array, but is of type: int

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my query

```
const messages = await Thread.findOne({_id: threadId}, {messages: {$slice: [10, -10]}})
```

This is the error:

```
MongoError: First argument to $slice must be an array, but is of type: int
```

Obviously I'm passing an array to $slice, so why am I getting this error?

Comment: the second value after $slice, must be positive: For the <number to return>, you must specify a positive number n to return the next n elements, starting after skipping the specified number.